# Creating ShortLink using FireBase Dynamic Link Domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener

Currently I am using `Google URL Shortener` to convert long url to short . Now I move to FireBase DynamicLink.

In FireBase Console I have added a project . After adding the project, i got a WebAPI Key . With in that project we need to register a app ( like IOS, Android).Then only I get dynamicLinkDomain.Using that url I can convert long url to Short url .

**My questions are**

1. is it possible to get DynamicLink Domain without adding/registering app within the project ?? if it is  yes, then how?
2. if i delete the app from the project ,Can i still use dynamicLinkDomain further for creating ShortLinks?.

Comment: did you find your answers?

Answer (score 0):

On this page: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/url-shortener it says the following:

> If you only want to create short links for web URLs, create a placeholder iOS app in your Firebase project from the Project Overview page of the Firebase console. (Specify any value for the bundle ID and skip the subsequent steps).

In my testing of this, it seems to work correctly for creating the links.

I also tested deleting the placeholder app afterwords, and the REST API is still creating short links for me.